# AZURE + SOCKET.IO: How do I know which port my Web App is using?

Tags: node.js, azure, socket.io, port

I went to a Hackathon last weekend and a Microsoft recruiter set me up with Azure for my Node.js project.

We used Socket.io with my project and had a hard time connecting the Client to the Server because we didn't know which port to connect to...

On our WebApp (not Azure VM), we had the following code:

```
var port = process.env.port || 3000;
```

On the client side of Socket.io, I had to specify an ip address to use along with it's port. I tried:

```
var socket = io('http://IP.AD.DRE.SSS:3000'); //And
var socket = io('http://IP.AD.DRE.SSS');      //And even a different Port
var socket = io('http://IP.AD.DRE.SSS:9999'); //And 443 and 80
```

And every iteration... I had to be doing something wrong. We ended up switching over to Digital Ocean because I knew how to use it but I really wanted to get this working.

Any Ideas?

**UPDATE:**
I changed it to 80 and my current error is: "Access Control Allow Origin." Note: My client is running on a server.

**UPDATE 2: Return of the OP**
Unfortunately, the CORS package for Node did not do the trick...

Some more info:
I'm not using Express or Connect. My server is on Azure (as an Azure Web App). My Client was on Localhost (Thanks to WebStorm).

Answer (score 0):

Azure Web Apps only listens on ports 80 & 443. Change the port to either of them and your app will work fine.

Comment: I changed it to 80 and my current error is: "Access Control Allow Origin." Note: My client is running on a server.

Comment: Sounds like you need to enable CORS in your Node.js client. You can get the package here, https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not do the trick... Some more info: I'm not using Express or Connect. My server is on Azure (as an Azure Web App). My Client was on Localhost (Thanks to WebStorm).

Answer (score 0):

Just leave the port off in the client string. You can connect using the URL alone. Look at my code I codefoster.com/commandmonkey as an example.